# Oops, something went wrong! Error: Error creating WebGL context

Tags: webgl, playwright

I am getting an issue "Oops, something went wrong! Error: Error creating WebGL context." while running my automation tests. I have installed x11 via "apt-get install -y x11-apps" and added "--disable-dev-shm-usage", "--no-sandbox", "--use-gl=angle", "--use-gl=swiftshader", in my browser launch args. how to resolve this issue.

installed x11 in docker
launching chromium with args: --disable-dev-shm-usage", "--no-sandbox", "--use-gl=angle", "--use-gl=swiftshader

Comment: Does your machine have a GPU or does it need to do emulation on the CPU?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had a script set in gitLab ci which ran selenium grid before executing playwright tests. when i got rid of selenium, this issue started showing webGL context error. Using `unset: display` in Gitlab script helped resolving this issue.

Comment: Please format your answer to make it more readable. For example, fix grammatical errors.